# Assignment Statement - Processing

Tags: variable-assignment

Can someone please explain if the following is a valid assignment statement?

```
x=y=Z;
```

For example

```
int x=9;
int y;
int Z; 

void setup() {
x=y=Z;
println(x);
println(y);
println(Z);
}
```

This also yields a different result than

```
void setup() {
int x=9;
int y;
int Z; 

x=y=Z;
println(x);
println(y);
println(Z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a valid assignment, but assignment works right to left. Breaking it down, it's equivalent to:

```
y = Z;
x = y;
```

The reason you're getting different values is likely because Z hasn't been defined and is likely looking at garbage. You could get different results again if you run your program several times.

Comment: I am using Processing!  Does this work in Processing?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I've not heard of 'Processing'. Can you provide me a link.